# Random characters printed in bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, bios, osdev

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code? I am using VirtualBox to run this and when it runs it, it simply spams random characters and then the screen is cleared black with the cursor in some random area. What is wrong with how I have loaded the second sector?

**boot.asm**

```
; 16 bit mode to use 2 byte align with 32 bit mode 4 byte aligned and 64 bit mode 8 byte aligned

%define NEW_LINE 0x0D, 0x0A

[BITS 16]
org 0x0000          ;IP= 0x0000, changes what everything is "offset from" to 0

section .text
    jmp 0x07c0:start     ; missing a - after 0x7c0 because each digit in hex is worth 4 bits
                    ; CS to7c0, IP = start

variables:
    align 2
    loadstr: db 'Loading Bootloader...', NEW_LINE
    align 2
    loadstr_len: dw 23

%include "bootloader_modules/vga.asm"    ; include BIOS VEGA functions
%include "bootloader_modules/drive.asm"  ; include BIOS drive write functions

start:
    align 2 
    mov ax, cs
    mov es, ax
    mov ds, ax

    bios_set_video_mode WIDE_TEXT_MODE
    bios_print_string loadstr, loadstr_len, 0, 0, 0, BLACK_COLOR | WHITE_COLOR
    bios_read_disk sector_2, HARD_DISK_DRIVE_N, 0, 2, 0, 1

    ;jmp $

    jmp 0x07c0:second_start

zero_fill times 510 - ($-$$) db 0x00
bootloader_signature: dw 0xAA55

second_start:

    bios_print_string disk_string, 12, 0, 0, 0, BLACK_COLOR | WHITE_COLOR

    jmp $

disk_string: db 'Hello There!',NEW_LINE
;times 512 - ($-second_start) db 0x00
sector_2: times 512 - ($-second_start) db 0x00
```

**vga.asm**:

```
;16_BIT_COLOR_PALLETE
%define BLACK_COLOR             0x000000
%define BLUE_COLOR              0x000001
%define GREEN_COLOR             0x000002
%define CYAN_COLOR              0x000003
%define RED_COLOR               0x000004
%define MAGENTA_COLOR           0x000005
%define BROWN_COLOR             0x000006
%define GREY_COLOR              0x000007
%define DARK_GREY_COLOR         0x000008
%define LIGH_BLUE_COLOR         0x000009
%define LIGHT_GREEN_COLOR       0x00000A
%define LIGHT_CYAN_COLOR        0x00000B
%define LIGHT_RED_COLOR         0x00000C
%define LIGHT_MAGENTA_COLOR     0x00000D
%define YELLOW_COLOR            0x00000E
%define WHITE_COLOR             0x00000F

%define BLACK_COLOR_M             0x000000
%define BLUE_COLOR_M              0x0000A8
%define GREEN_COLOR_M             0x00A800
%define CYAN_COLOR_M              0x00A8A8
%define RED_COLOR_M               0xA80000
%define MAGENTA_COLOR_M           0xA800A8
%define ORANGE_COLOR_M            0xA85400
%define GREY_COLOR_M              0xA8A8A8
%define DARK_GREY_COLOR_M         0x545454
%define LIGH_BLUE_COLOR_M         0x5454FE
%define LIGHT_GREEN_COLOR_M       0x54FE54
%define LIGHT_CYAN_COLOR_M        0x54FEFE
%define BRIGHT_RED_COLOR_M        0xFE5454
%define BRIGHT_MAGENTA_COLOR_M    0xFE54FE
%define YELLOW_COLOR_M            0xFEFE54
%define WHITE_COLOR_M             0xFEFEFE

;VIDEO_MODES
%define SHORT_TEXT_MODE      0x01
%define SHORT_TEXT_MODE_C    0x02
%define WIDE_TEXT_MODE       0x03
%define WIDE_TEXT_MODE_C     0x04

%define GRAPHICAL_MODE              0x05
%define GRAPHICAL_MODE_C            0x13
;%define GRAPHICAL_MODE_SHORT       0x05
%define GRAPHICAL_MODE_SHORT_C      0x13
;%define GRAPHICAL_MODE_SHORT_MC    0x13
;%define GRAPHICAL_MODE_MC          0x00
;%define GRAPHICAL_MODE_WIDE        0x00
%define GRAPHICAL_MODE_WIDE_C       0x12
%define GRAPHICAL_MODE_WIDE_MC      0x11

%macro bios_set_video_mode 1

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, %1

    int 0x10

%endmacro

%macro bios_print_string 6

    mov bp, %1    ; [ES:BP] is far pointer string to write

    mov ah, 0x13  ; write string
    mov al, 0x01  ; update cursoer after writing
    mov bh, %3    ; page number
    mov bl, %6    ; color attributes
    mov cx, [%2]  ; number of characters in string
    mov dh, %4    ; row
    mov dl, %5    ; column

    int 0x10

%endmacro
```

**drive.asm**:

```
%define HARD_DISK_DRIVE_N 0x80
%define FLOPPY_DISK_DRIVE_N 0x0
%define COMPACT_DISK_DRIVE_N 0xE0

%macro bios_read_disk 6

    mov bx, %1 ; buffer pointer, the offset

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov dl, %2 ; drive number, 80 for hard drives
    mov ch, %3 ; cylinder number
    mov cl, %4 ; sector number
    mov dh, %5 ; head number
    mov al, %6 ; sectors to read

    int 0x13

    jc .read_error

    bios_print_string DRIVE_READ_SUCCESS_MSG, DRIVE_READ_SUCCESS_MSG_len, 0, 0, 0, BLACK_COLOR | WHITE_COLOR

    .read_error:
    bios_print_string DRIVE_READ_ERROR_MSG, DRIVE_READ_ERROR_MSG_len, 0, 0, 0, BLACK_COLOR | WHITE_COLOR

%endmacro

DRIVE_READ_ERROR_MSG: db 'Error reading from drive, carry flag set', NEW_LINE
DRIVE_READ_ERROR_MSG_len: dw 41
DRIVE_READ_SUCCESS_MSG: db 'Suc', NEW_LINE
DRIVE_READ_SUCCESS_MSG_len: dw 5
```

Comment: It would help if you would make this an [mcve] and show us the contents of vga.asm and drive.asm. We don't know where in memory you loaded the kernel but the way you coded it would have to be at physical address 0x07e00 in memory. Anywhere else will cause it to read the strings from the wrong memory offsets. You also don't set up your own stack SS:SP which is really needed before you read more sectors into memory. You don't want to read new sectors on top of the stack that the BIOS set.

Comment: @MichaelPetch the label after the 512th byte is put in to ES. I also tried specifically putting 512 in to ES too. Yet none of these work

Comment: The offset of label `second_start` should not go in ES, It should go in BX and ES should contain 0x07c0 (which you already set when the bootloader started). Please edit the question to show what is in drive.asm and just in case show vga.asm as well. If you don't it is very difficult to help since the bug isn't in the code you are showing.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that was a typo, second_start is actually loaded in to BX and I have shown both the included files

Comment: VirtualBox has a [debugger](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#ts_debugger) so you should be able to narrow down the problem.

Comment: So I changed the buffer pointer loaded into "al" to "second_start" and the result is different. The previous strings are constantly reprinted

Comment: Beyond fixing the problem with the sector (that you have apparently fixed) your drive.asm code after printing `suc` falls right into the code that prints that there was an error right after. You'll need to skip over the error code when there is success. Your VGA macros/code are a bit unusual. You use `mov cx, [%2]` which means you need to pass all the string lengths in memory (which is odd way to do it), but then when you print `disk_string` you pass the length as a constant 12 (not a memory address).

Comment: You really should modify yuor vga macros so that you pass the size directly as an immediate (constant) and use `mov cx, %2` instead of `mov cx, [%2]` . That would also mean you'd have to change `DRIVE_READ_ERROR_MSG_len: dw 41` to `DRIVE_READ_ERROR_MSG_len EQU $-DRIVE_READ_ERROR_MSG"` similar change with `DRIVE_READ_SUCCESS_MSG_len`

Comment: thanks, I finally fixed the main bug. It was printing many characters over and over because I had moved an address to the parameter for the string length. I guess something wrapped round somehow? I am not sure, neither am I sure why it only repeated printing strings I had created. At least now the original main bug is fixed now. thanks!